# New objects: new operator vs serialization

Tags: java, serialization

As I understood from what I've read there are basically two ways to create completely new objects in Java: 1) by using `new` operator and 2) by means of serialization (for deep copying, for example). All other object manipulations (like assigning, for instance) deal with references to existing objects. But what is the difference between the two above mentioned ways in terms of inner logic? It seems that one difference is that serialization somehow doesn't use constructor methods. Am I right? Are there other differences?

By 'inner logic' I mean how the compiler (or whoever deals with it) creates object step-by-step, what algorithm it uses, what methods are used for that and so on. More like what Margaret Bloom was writing about in her answer but in more detail.

***FURTHER CONFUSION CLARIFICATION:***

So do I get it right that during deserialization the copy of the object:

```
class Class1 {
    static ARRAY_LENGTH = 10;
    public class1() {
        int[] anArray = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH];
        anArray[0] = 5;
        ...
        anArray[9] = -2;
    }
}
```

will include a copy of the array created elsehow (how? since no constructor has been called)? And furthermore, though the original array (before serialization) has been created by using `static` field (which is lost during serialization) its deserialized copy will nevetheless be identical to the original array?

Comment: Well there's `clone()` too.

Comment: And several techniques in JNI.

Comment: You have to write the "inner logic" of the constructors and serialization code yourself. So the answer to your question us "whatever difference you make". Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @markspace Thank you, I obviously forgot about `clone()`.

Comment: @EJP Thank you, I overlooked that one.

Comment: @Raedwald By 'inner logic' I meant how the compiler (or whoever deals with it) creates object step-by-step, what algorithm it uses, what methods are used for that and so on. More like what Margaret Bloom was writing about in her answer but in more detail.

Comment: Don't provide clarification in comments. Instead, edit your question so it is clearer.

Comment: The key to this riddle is the knowledge that when you call the `new` operator, two things happen: firstly, an "empty" new object is allocated (with all the fields initialised to the standard default values), and then, initialisation code (constructor and instance initialiser blocks) is run. For deserialization, only the first step is performed, and the fields are initialised by the deserialization process.

Comment: @biziclop Thanks a lot! That finally cleared my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serialization and the `new` operator are completely different things, though they both result in a reference to a newly allocated object.

You can find detailed information about the `new` operator in chapter *15.9.4 Run-Time Evaluation of Class Instance Creation Expressions* of the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf).

> At run time, evaluation of a class instance creation expression is as follows.
>   [...]
>   **Next, space is allocated for the new class instance.**
>   [...]
>   The new object contains new instances of all the fields declared in the specified
>   class type and all its superclasses.
>   [...]
>   Next, the actual arguments to the constructor are evaluated, left-to-right.  [...]
>   **Next, the selected constructor of the specified class type is invoked.** This results in
>   invoking at least one constructor for each superclass of the class type.
>   The value of a class instance creation expression is a **reference to the newly created
>   object** of the specified class. Every time the expression is evaluated, **a fresh object
>   is created.**

<sup>Editing mine</sup>
So long story short, `new` allocates space for a new object (specifically space for its fields), initialize its fields with their default values and invokes the chosen constructor.

---

[Java Serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) is another matter entirely.

> The ability to store and retrieve JavaTM objects is essential to building all but the most transient applications.   **The key to storing and retrieving objects in a serialized form is representing the state of objects sufficient to reconstruct the object(s).**
>   <sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

Which means that serialization was designed to allow the programmer to save objects states into a persistent medium (abstracted into *stream* within Java) and [read them back](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#2971).

As such, deserializiation does not invoke constructors since the object state is restored automatically by reading it out the stream. You can override the default behavior though.

> Reading an object from the ObjectInputStream is analogous to creating a new object. Just as a new object's constructors are invoked in the order from the superclass to the subclass, an object being read from a stream is deserialized from superclass to subclass. **The readObject or readObjectNoData method is called instead of the constructor** for each Serializable subclass during deserialization.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

---

Said that, I would like to stress out how using `new` and serialization are totally unrelated things from a conceptual point of view.
In the first case you are creating your own new object, in the latter you are reading a previously saved object (possibly by someone else).

Even though they can be thought as similar for their final result, you should have, in your mind, a really clear distinction between the twos.

Comment: Yes, they are different things but I would disagree that they're unrelated. In fact it's often vitally important to see the two as two sides of the same coin. (For example when you're establishing class invariants.)

Comment: It's generally understood that they are "completely different" in Java.  For example, in *Effective Java* Joshua Bloch points out that serialization is extra-linguistic.  Serialization is not specified by the language spec, it's specified by the API.  I see what you are saying, but the generally accepted answer by Java experts is that the two are far more different than alike.

Answer (score 0):

New operator is use to create object in memory whereas serialization is the concept belongs to data persistence and it could also be used for creating a new object in memory.

If an object implements  java.io.Serializable it will be marked as Serializable Object and data in object could be converted to byte stream (serialize) and we could use this byte stream data to create a new object in memory (desrialize). Java supports 2 objects for serialize and deserialize, they are ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream

Answer (score 0):

Disagree with `deserializiation does not invoke constructors`:

In fact, *Deserializiation* just does not invoke the constructors defined in the class body. As depends on `java.reflect`, it of course need to invoke constructors to produce a `Object` from a `Class`. It just invoke the custom constructors created by **`sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(Class<?> var1, Constructor var2)`**.